# Android XML Error parsing XML unbound prefix

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I had 2 errors but i got one fixed. I still have the Error parsing XML unbound prefix error thou at the com.admob.android.ads wats wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
/>

<com.admob.android.ads.AdView
  android:id="@+id/ad" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  xmlns:backgroundColor="#000000"
  xmlns:primaryTextColor="FFFFFF"
  xmlns:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  ads:adSize="BANNER"
  ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
  /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to set layout configuration on the main tag (RelativeLayout) and to set the namespace of ads:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
```

Comment: So i replaced <RelativeLayout> with 
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.suit.AdmobTest"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>                                                                     and im still getting the same error. BTW how can i make the code look as nice as yours, not a mess like it is now?

Comment: at line <com.admob.and... i have error  Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'adUnitId' in package 'com.suit.AdmobTest'
 - error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'loadAdOnCreate' in package 
  'com.suit.AdmobTest'

Comment: Sorry, the namespace should be: http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads. I updated the answer

Comment: Thanks there are no errors anymore but the app crashes. Will try on my actual phone.